# matplotlib RuntimeError: Could not allocate memory for image

Tags: python, memory-management, matplotlib

So, I'm receiving "RuntimeError: Could not allocate memory for image" from matplotlib when I try to re-size my image on the canvas. The images are large DICOM (.dcm) files that have been allocated memory using ctypes' PyMem_Malloc. They've been allocated 16 bits per pixel (they need to be Hi-Res). The problem comes after we've re-sized the canvas and attempt to draw the re-sized image using:

```
self.view.canvas.draw()
```

Here's the specific exception being thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 1355, in _onMotion
    FigureCanvasBase.motion_notify_event(self, x, y, guiEvent=evt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1625, in motion_notify_event
    self.callbacks.process(s, event)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 265, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 191, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\widgets.py", line 1258, in onmove
    self.update()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\widgets.py", line 1236, in update
    self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 384, in restore_region
    renderer = self.get_renderer()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 404, in get_renderer
    self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi, debug=False)
RuntimeError: Could not allocate memory for image
```

The images themselves shouldn't need more allocation, correct? So what could be the problem here? Does matplotlib limit the size in memory that the canvas can hold? Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Matplotlib internally converts things to floats for display, so a copy is made and more memory is allocated for any non floating point data you pass in.  They won't (if I remember correctly?) be converted until the canvas is drawn for the first time, which could explain the timing.  If it's not the first time you're drawing the canvas, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: It's not the first draw :( We allow the user to select/drag a rectangular area of the image, and then zoom to that portion of the image, filling the canvas as much as possible with that selected area. The image is in a wxPython ScrolledWindow, which contains the entire image, so the whole image is enlarged but only the selected area is shown (Well, hypothetically speaking, this is what we're trying to acheive). I've successfully enlarged the image 150% it's normal size, but beyond that seems to throw this memory allocation exception.